# Adding Http headers from string in C#

Tags: c#, http-headers, webclient

I've got some C# method which gets JSON data from Uri specified by user. User also can add some extra headers - my method gets them as a string (separated by new line '\n'). If it's single header there is no problem. But what if user wants to add few headers? I'm using WebClient class.

Piece of method:

```
using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
            {
                switch (Method.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "GET":
                        {
                            web.Headers.Add(UserHeaders);
                            result = web.DownloadString(UserUri);
                            break;
                        }
                }
```

If header is like below there is no problem:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

But how to add few headers - in example:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Charset: utf-8
```

Comment: try `web.Headers.AddRange(UserHeaders.Split("\n"));`

Comment: try splitting your `UserHeaders` into an array and then loop through the array to push the items to the `Headers`

Comment: I think to use loop as a last resort. I'm looking for another solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any other solution than itering through all elements and adding them separetly.

My simple method:

```
public void AddCustomHeaders(WebClient web, string headers)
    {
        List<string> listOfHeaders = new List<string>();
        listOfHeaders = headers.Split('\n').ToList();

        foreach (var header in listOfHeaders)
            web.Headers.Add(header);
    }
```